# Changing a chart object with Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am working on a larger project that involves making a worksheet with up to 100 different charts (in this case XY scatter charts). I have seen on other threads that it is not efficient to activate charts every time you want to make a change. In this sub I am just running through a loop to create 120 blank charts, and will later add data and format. Here is my code:

```
Global Const numCharts = 120
Private Charts()
ReDim Charts(numCharts)

Sub createCharts()
    For graphIndex = 1 To numCharts
        'adds the new chart in the specified loaction
        Set Charts(graphIndex) = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects.Add(Left:=chartTopLeftX, Top:=chartTopLeftY, Width:=chartWidth, Height:=chartHeight)
        Charts(graphIndex).Name = activeSheetName & graphIndex
        Charts(graphIndex).ChartType = xlXYScatter

        'changes the top left coordinate varibales for the following chart
        If graphIndex Mod 2 = 1 Then
            chartTopLeftX = chartTopLeftX + chartWidth + chartGap
            'chartTopLeftY = chartTopLeftY
        Else
            chartTopLeftX = chartTopLeftX - chartWidth - chartGap
            chartTopLeftY = chartTopLeftY + chartHeight + chartGap
        End If
    Next graphIndex
End Sub
```

The `Charts(graphIndex).Name` line works fine, but I get an error on the `Charts(graphIndex).ChartType` line. If I activate the chart first I can just use `ActiveChart.ChartType`, but I am trying to avoid that. Hopefully this makes sense. I have run into this issue in the past when working with chart objects, but can't seem to find a good explanation on why?

Edit: I'm sorry I should have specified this, but there are many variables decalred in the module, outside of this sub. The code runs perfectly fine without the `Charts(graphIndex).ChartType` line. I may not be handling this correctly, but I tried to create an array to hold the chart objects.

Comment: What is `Charts`?

Comment: this `Charts(graphIndex) ` will error out as #9. the code you have posted will never get past that line.

Comment: @cyboashu Sorry still new to posting on here. I edited now, but the `Charts()` array was declared and defined separately in the module. The issue I was having was just with changing the chart type without having to activate the chart.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Observe that `ChartType` is a member of the `Chart` object, not the `ChartObject` object. So to assign the `ChartType`, you need to handle the `ChartObject.Chart`.

```
Sub createCharts()
    Dim newChart as ChartObject
    For graphIndex = 1 To numCharts
        'adds the new ChartObject in the specified loaction
        Set newChart = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects.Add(Left:=chartTopLeftX, Top:=chartTopLeftY, Width:=chartWidth, Height:=chartHeight)
        newChart.Name = activeSheetName & graphIndex
        'handles the .Chart:
        newChart.Chart.ChartType = xlXYScatter
```

**NOTE:** This will potentially fail with an Index Out of Range error, unless the chart *already exists*. So your code either doesn't work at all (you can't add a chart this way, to a sheet with 0 charts on it), or it's replicating a bunch of extra charts, unnecessarily. You'll need to fix that.

Alternatively, chain the `Chart` property of the `ChartObjects.Add`, like:

```
Set Charts(graphIndex) = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects.Add(Left:=chartTopLeftX, Top:=chartTopLeftY, Width:=chartWidth, Height:=chartHeight).Chart
```

But rather than referring to them constantly as indexed members of the `Charts` collection, I think the first approach to use an object variable is best. If you don't like to work with the `ChartObject`, just combine the two methods above:

```
Dim cht as Chart
Set cht = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects.Add( _
    Left:=chartTopLeftX, _
    Top:=chartTopLeftY, _
    Width:=chartWidth, _
    Height:=chartHeight).Chart
cht.Parent.Name = activeSheetName & graphIndex
cht.ChartType = xlXYScatter
```

Comment: Thank you, that worked. Is there an easy way to keep track of which properties are linked to the `Chart` property and which are linked to the `ChartObject`?

Comment: @ChrisHill well the Intellisense should tip you off if you're using strongly-typed variables, but implicit collections don't always play nicely. You should bookmark the Excel object model reference, [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff846392(v=office.14).aspx) and refer to the pages on each `Chart` and `ChartObject` respectively. (There's a wealth of other information there, as well!)

Comment: To address the duplicate charts, this is just one sub in a series of about 10 that regenerates the charts. The first sub always deletes all current charts. Then this sub is called to recreate them.

Comment: sure, that's out of scope, I just mention it as a possible problem since I don't have your full code. In any case. `Set Charts(graphIndex) = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects.Add(...` seems like it will always fail if the `Charts` collection doesn't already contain `graphIndex` number of charts.

Comment: I am not having that issue, but I think it was due to luck and not my understanding (not generally a good thing when coding). I edited my original post to show the declaration and defining of `Charts()`. Is there a different way I should handle this? The reason I chose to use an array, was it seems easier to reference and edit in other subs. Later I add data, format, and edit axis to each chart using other subs. This seemed like a decent way to handle this.

Comment: OK, so what you've done there is shadow the built-in/default `Charts` collection, with a local variable of the same name. You don't get the error because you have declared it as an array, and you've `ReDim` to an appropriate size.

Comment: Worth noting: it's preferable to avoid using built-in names for variables, because it makes for very confusing and difficult to debug code.

Answer (score 0):

Building on the answer of @David-Zemens:

`ChartObjects.Add` is older syntax, which still works fine, but newer syntax might serve you better in this case.

Use this to build the charts (2007+):

```
Dim cht as Chart
Set cht = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart( _
    XlChartType:= xlXYScatter, _
    Left:=chartTopLeftX, _
    Top:=chartTopLeftY, _
    Width:=chartWidth, _
    Height:=chartHeight).Chart
cht.Parent.Name = activeSheetName & graphIndex
```

or this (2013+):

```
Dim cht as Chart
Set cht = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart2( _
    Style:=240, _
    XlChartType:= xlXYScatter, _
    Left:=chartTopLeftX, _
    Top:=chartTopLeftY, _
    Width:=chartWidth, _
    Height:=chartHeight, _
    NewLayout:=True).Chart
cht.Parent.Name = activeSheetName & graphIndex
```

AddChart inserts a chart with the Office 2007 default styling, AddChart2 inserts one  with the Office 2013 styling, with the option of applying a different style. Style 240 is the default style for an XY Scatter chart in 2013, other chart types have their own styles.

FWIW, I always add a chart and populate and format it, then add the next chart. Otherwise it's too complicated and too much bookkeeping, and I'm always afraid too much can go wrong.